# How identify element by ai keyword?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, there is a way to identify the "li class=""...> who has a "a id=""...>" tag with a specific ai="2711766". How can i identify them by "ai"? If were "id" i would use "getElementById" but in this case, identify by "ai", i don't know how to do it!

```
...
<li class="" style="background-color: rgb(246, 237, 245);"> … </li>
<li class="" style="background-color: rgb(246, 237, 245);"> … </li>
<li class="" style="background-color: rgb(246, 237, 245);">
    <a id="a_32447396" class="aVideo" ai="2711766" i="há 4 horas">
        <div class="imgVideo" onmouseover="startThumbSlide('32447396', '0')">
            <div class="photo2">
                <div id="f_32447396" class="lazyVideos"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3 style="color: rgb(133, 6, 123);"> … </h3>
    </a>
    <p> … </p>
</li>
<li class=""> … </li>
<li class="" style="background-color: rgb(246, 237, 245);"> … </li>
<li class="" style="background-color: rgb(246, 237, 245);"> … </li>
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should comment on answers instead of posting an answer. I do not know if you can change the website html, also you can assign data values using javascript

Answer (score 0):

try using `data` attriubte.

```
  <a id="a_32447396" class="aVideo" data-ai="2711766" data-i="há 4 horas">
```

You can reach the values with `dataset` like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('a_32447396')
console.log(el.dataset.ai); //2711766
```

Answer (score 0):

The *ai* is an attribute. Knowing this you could get the value searching the element by [tag name using getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getattribute.asp) instead by id and then get the attribute like this:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]; // in this example the first link is taken!
alert(element.getAttribute("ai"));
```

Output is:

```
2711766
```

The drawback of this is, that you will get all elements of the given type (f.e. links - a) and you need to iterate over them.